# Lost connection to both OS and IPMI after adding VLAN config in CentOS

Tags: centos, vlan, ipmi, supermicro

I have a Supermicro X9DRD-IF motherboard with IPMI onboard.
I'm completely losing network (both IPMI and OS) after adding VLAN support in OS network configuration.
Network cable is connected into LAN1 port. IPMI is configured as shared. IPMI VLAN is not set. IPMI firmware was updated to latest version.
Network comes with `VLAN 171` untagged `(XX.XX.XX.0/26)` and `VLAN 169 (YY.YY.YY.128/27)` tagged. Switch is HP Procurve 2824 J4903A.

My IPMI network config in BIOS:

```
Configuration Address source: [Static]
Station IP address XX.XX.XX.003
Subnet mask 255.255.255.192
Station MAC address 00-25-90-4e-73-7b (not editable)
Gateway IP address XX.XX.XX.001
```

Config with these two files is working fine:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0
DEVICE="br0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
BROADCAST="XX.XX.XX.63"
IPADDR="XX.XX.XX.4"
NETMASK="255.255.255.192"
NETWORK="XX.XX.XX.0"
GATEWAY="XX.XX.XX.1"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Bridge"

cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:
DEVICE="eth0"
HWADDR="00:25:90:4E:9A:E4"
ONBOOT="yes"
BRIDGE="br0"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
```

But just after I add VLAN config file, and restart network, I lose connection. No ping both on IPMI and OS IPs. This is my VLAN config:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.169:
VLAN="yes"
DEVICE="eth0.169"
HWADDR="00:25:90:4E:9A:E4"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
BRIDGE="br0"
BOOTPROTO="none"
TYPE="Ethernet"
```

Also I tried to add driver option as suggested [here](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=3477) and [here](http://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=13932)

```
options e1000e CrcStripping=0
```

in `/etc/modprobe.d/e1000e.conf`, but it didn't help.

By the way, I have similar VLAN config working fine on another server with older X8STi-F and CentOS 5.8, but on new server I have no more ideas what I have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any option to use a dedicated IMPI port? Shared is not a good option if you plan to use OS-level VLAN configurations. You typically have to have the eth0/first interface and the IPMI on the same VLAN...

See: [How does IPMI sideband share the ethernet port with the host?](https://serverfault.com/questions/259792/how-does-ipmi-sideband-share-the-ethernet-port-with-the-host/259948#259948)

Comment: They are on the same VLAN. But it works only until additional VLAN configured. I have an option to use a dedicated port, but it will increase collocation cost for me. If I'll not find the answer or workaround, then I'll have to buy it.