# Two Linux servers with public IP addresses and IPMI LAN

Tags: linux, ipmi

I'm experimenting with two servers with public IP addresses to get LAN connection with IPMI. For IPMI I'm using local IP addresses (same NIC).

```
ipmitool -I open lan set 1 ipaddr 192.168.2.50
Setting LAN IP Address to 192.168.2.50
ipmitool -I open lan set 1 netmask 255.255.255.0
Setting LAN Subnet Mask to 255.255.255.0
ipmitool -I open lan set 1 snmp SOMESTRING
Setting LAN SNMP Community String to SOMESTRING
ipmitool -d /dev/ipmi0 user set name 2 admin
ipmitool -d /dev/ipmi0 user set password 2 SOMESTRING
ipmitool -d /dev/ipmi0 channel setaccess 1 2  callin=on ipmi=on link=on privilege=4
ipmitool -d /dev/ipmi0 lan set 1 arp respond on
ipmitool -d /dev/ipmi0 lan set 1 arp generate on
ipmitool -d /dev/ipmi0 lan set 1 arp interval 5
```

Two computers with IPMI LAN addresses 192.168.2.50 and 192.168.2.51
I configured, but I'm just getting:

```
ipmitool -I lan -U admin -H 192.168.2.51 -a chassis power status
Password: 
Error: Unable to establish LAN session
Unable to get Chassis Power Status
```

Even if I'm using same computer with same IPMI address (192.168.2.50). I get same error message.
I'm used strace tool to check. UDP socket gets connection timeout.

Tried reset BMC but with no results.

```
ipmitool mc reset cold
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

We have CISCO switch for our servers. Computers 1 and computer 2 connected to same switch. Computer 1 has public IP 193.219.X.Y1 and computer 2 has public IP 193.219.X.Y2. Computer's 1 IPMI address 192.168.2.50 and computers's 2 IPMI address 192.168.2.51. I can't use public IP address for IPMI because they are limited.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do a bit better?

Comment: I want to control another computer using IPMI.

Comment: [Shared NICs are a real pain.](http://serverfault.com/a/259948/126632) If you can, use a dedicated NIC.

Comment: "UDP socket gets connection timeout."... that's not quite how UDP works.  You'd be better off using `tcpdump` or adding -vvv to the ipmitool command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another computer on the same LAN with an IP address that is in the same subnet as those of the IPMI BMC's.

You just said you're using a computer with the same IPMI address. Your BMC should have a completely different address to the computer it's running on and for that matter any other machine on the network or else you'll get a clash.  It doesn't matter that's it's using a shared NIC.

i.e IPMI of the server should be 192.168.2.50 and the server should be "something that's not 192.168.2.50".

---

Assuming the above is correct check that on your server that contains the IPMI BMC that the OpenIPMI packages are properly installed.

Check if the `/dev/ipmi0` device file exists.  If it doesn't. Create it like this:

```
SuSE, Red Hat or CentOS: "/etc/init.d/ipmi start"
Debian 4: "/usr/share/ipmitool/ipmi.init.basic"
Debian 5: "modprobe ipmi_devintf; modprobe ipmi_si"
```

Then try the following as root:

```
ipmitool lan set 1 ipsrc static
ipmitool lan set 1 ipaddr 192.168.2.50
ipmitool lan set 1 netmask 255.255.255.0
ipmitool lan set 1 arp respond on
ipmitool lan set 1 access on
```

Check the changes:
    ipmitool lan print 1

Warm reset the BMC

The ipsrc static line is critical as it may still use DHCP after applying all the other settings.

All this was based on the following [link](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Configuring_IPMI_under_Linux_using_ipmitool) which I used originally to get it going for me. Along with I think the warm reset.

Note: As mentioned in the comments below.  Some BMC's require the default gateway to be set.  I found that to be true for Supermicro servers but thought that was a one off.  It seems it may be a common problem.

Set the default gateway with:

```
 ipmitool lan set 1 defgw ipaddr 192.168.50.xxx
```

Comment: I added more information for question. Please check.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: It worked at least get info from same computer. Setting gateway solved it. I need to ask network admin which local IP addresses I can use. For now I accepting your answer. You may update your answer. Problem was not specifying gateway.

Comment: I've had that issue on some systems as well.  By not setting gateway despite the fact that gateway shouldn't be needed when connected from local lan.  I thought that was just me.  Are you using Supermicro servers?

Comment: We are using servers (without any brand) with Intel system boards. Intel system board model is S5000PAL (slightly outdated).

Comment: To warm-reset the BMC: `ipmitool mc reset warm`. If it doesn't work (it doesn't on my Dell R510), then do ti cold (which takes a minute or 2 to complete): `ipmitool mc reset cold`